# I want to show cart items number if any or nothing, simple CART text

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, navigation

I am making a custom WooCommerce site and stuck at coding the CART link.

I want the link to look simple text "CART" when there is no item in it. But to show the number of items if any like "CART (1)"--- is it possible ?

I am currently using this code which I feel shows "0" of no item.

`<a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_page_link(12)); ?>">Cart (<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?>)</a>`

Can someone please help me out with this??? I want a conditional php code to show Cart items number only if there are any, otherwise show nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You're already on the right track. Simply add conditional if 0

```php
<?PHP

$cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
$cart_count = $cart_count ? "({$cart_count})" : ''; // if 0, become empty string
$cart_link = wc_get_cart_url();

$cart_button = "<a href='{$cart_link}'>Cart {$cart_count}</a>";

echo $cart_button;
```

Comment: it shows syntax wrong and not accepting in code.

Comment: Well I just typed that on top of my head, so maybe mistyped something. What's the error message? O**r probably you're on older PHP version that doesn't support that string concat?**

Comment: Buddy, I am not on older PHP version. Wait, I will show you what it says--- syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)

Comment: Maybe that's just a missing semi colon at the end of the $cart_button line then?

Comment: @Rup Ah yes, missing semi colon on $cart_button, will edit it in, thanks